Rationality of generating functions and exponential generating functions
Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of positive integers. Is there a connection between the rationality of the (ordinary) generating function of this sequence and the rationality of its exponential generating function? More precisely, does the rationality of one imply the other?

In fact, I claim that they cannot both be rational unless $a_n$ is eventually zero (making both polynomial).
If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is the Maclaurin series of a non-polynomial rational function $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ then it has radius of convergence $R = \frac{1}{\min\{|x_0| : q(x_0) = 0\}} < \infty$. Then by Cauchy-Hadamard we know that eventually $a_n \leq \frac{1}{(R-\epsilon)^n}$ for all $\epsilon>0$.
Then Cauchy-Hadamard gives $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{n!}} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(R-\epsilon) \sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$ so the EGF has infinite radius of convergence, and cannot be a non-polynomial rational function.
Conversely, if the EGF is a non-polynomial rational function then it has finite radius of convergence so the OGF has zero radius of convergence.
If $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{n!}} = 1/R < \infty$ then for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{n!}} > 1/R - \epsilon$ infinitely often, so $|a_n| > n!\left(\frac{1}{R} - \epsilon\right)^n$, so $\sqrt[n]{a_n} > \sqrt[n]{n!}\left(\frac{1}{R} - \epsilon\right) $ infinitely often. As $n \to \infty$, the RHS tends to $+\infty$ so $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is unbounded and has limit superior $+\infty$. So by Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence is $1$.

That makes sense, thank you. Would you mind showing me the converse too, please? I tried to use a similar argument to the one you used but it seems I can't get the radius of convergence of the OGF to be zero.

@Mec Done as requested.

Thank you for the edit. This may be a dumb question because I have not dealt with limsups in a while, but why is the inequality $\sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{n!}}>1/R-\varepsilon$ true for infinitely many $n$'s? I think I believe it if $1/R$ were the liminf.

If $1/R$ were the liminf then we would have that inequality for all sufficiently large $n$, not just infinitely many. @Mec
